# Aplicar taxas conforme o numero de livros vendidos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, algoritmo

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Numa editora paga-se x% ao autor e o mesmo tem vários patamares. Se o autor vender até 1000unid livros ele recebe 10% da venda. Entre os 1000unid e os 5000unid recebe 12% e entre os 5001 e os 15000unid recebe 15%. Durante o primeiro periodo de contas ele recebeu o que tinha direito de 850unid(a 10%) que foram as suas vendas. Imagina que no periodo seguinte ele vendeu mais 500, então ele tem direito a receber 150unid(a 10%) e 350unid(a 12%) mas também pode haver o caso em que ele vende mais 6000 e então ele tem direito a receber 150unid(a 10%) 4000unid(a 12%) e 1850unid(a 15%). Como posso escrever isso em php de forma que as percentagens possam encaixar a cada quantidade, respeitando já as quantidades que foram pagas e mostrar isso em uma tabela?

```
| DE         | Até         |      Taxa    |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 1          |        1000 |     10%      | 
| 1001       |        5000 |     12%      |
| 5001       |       15000 |     15%      |
```

Comment: Inicialmente coloque isso numa tabela e poste junto a pergunta. Fica mais facil entender. Por exemplo: eu não sei a porcentagem que ele receberia entre 5001 a 14999.

Comment: acabei de atualizar

Comment: Não entendi porque os periodos tem de ser cumulativos e porque, sendo cumulativos, recebe percentuais de todas as faixas. Imagine que no primeiro periodo ele tenha vendido 6000 unidades. Pela regra ele receberá 15% de 6000. Certo?  Por que você sugere que ele receberá percentuais das 3 faixas?